# Google Sheets onEdit capitalize script function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I appreciate the collective wisdom of the group.

I found these snippets of code on the internet and have tried to adopt them to my situation and by no means intend to plagiarize anyone ...

I want to capitalize every word in a cell. I invoke the follow script from my onEdit(e) function. Doesn't do anything. This just doesn't look like right and obviously I am missing important data ...

```
function onEdit(e) { TitleCase(e); }

function TitleCase(e) {
  return e.toString().split(/\b/).map(function (word) {
    return e ? e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';
  }).join('');
}
```

I am a newbie and I really appreciate any guidance.

Jim

Comment: Can you post the question by including one question? If your question has 2 questions, can you separate your current 2 questions as each post including one question? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: yes, sorry will do

Comment: Done. thank you sorry

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question for your question. About `I invoke the follow script from my onEdit(e) function.`, in this case, how do you execute the function of `TitleCase`? If you execute it from `onEdit`, can you show the script of `onEdit`? Because I thought that it is required to correctly know about the value of `e`.

Comment: Updated question with onEdit function written

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When you want to run the script of `TitleCase` from the simple trigger of OnEdit, it is required to directly put the values to the cell.
- From your script, `e` is the event object. So using this object, the value is retrieved and put it to the cell.
- In your script of `TitleCase`, I think that it is almost the correct. But, I think that `e` of `return e ? e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';` should be `word`.
- From your additinal request of `How would it be further modified to only perform this for one specific column?`, in this case, it is required to check the edited column.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, please put the text to a cell. By this, the script is run.

```
function onEdit(e) {TitleCase(e);}

function TitleCase(e) {
  const columnNumber = 1; // Please set the specific column number. For example, 1 is the column "A".
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getColumn() != columnNumber) return;
  const value = range.getValue().toString().split(/\b/).map(function(word) {
    return word ? word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';
  }).join('');
  range.setValue(value);
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Hello -- If 'comment' is not the right way, please let me know. The modification that you wrote works beautifully... Thank you. How would it be further modified to only perform this for one specific column? Thank you very much!

Comment: @James Woods Thank you for replying. You can freely comment to the posted answer. About your additional request, I updated my answer, could you please confirm it? The modified sample script is run when the edited column is the column "A".

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you for your quick detailed response!